# $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ proof of limit (Spivak)

Tags: calculus, limits

Could you please help me with this proof? 
$$
f(x)=x^4 + \frac1x 
$$
Prove using $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ that
$$
\lim_{x \to 1} f(x)=2
$$

This problem is from Spivak's book Chapter 5 problem $3-iii.$

Comment: Do you mean $f(x)\to l = 2$ for $x\to a=1$?

Answer (score 3):

**hint**:$\left|\dfrac{x^5+1-2x}{x}\right| = \left|\dfrac{(x-1)P(x)}{x}\right|\leq K|x-1|$, for a suitable $K > 0$ for those $x's$ in an appropriate neighborhood of $1$

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* Use the triangle inequality
$$\left|x^4 + \frac 1x - 2\right| \leq \left|x^4 - 1\right| + \left| \frac 1x - 1\right|$$

Now find a $\delta_1, \delta_2$ for each of the two terms on the right. Then $\delta = \min(\delta_1, \delta_2)$ will work for the expression overall.

That is: given $\epsilon > 0$, find $\delta_1$ such that

$$0 < |x - 1| < \delta_1 \ \Longrightarrow \ \left|x^4 - 1\right| < \frac\epsilon 2$$
and find $\delta_2$ such that
$$0 < |x - 1| < \delta_2 \ \Longrightarrow \ \left| \frac 1x - 1\right| < \frac\epsilon 2$$

Then

$$\begin{align} & \ 0 < |x-1| < \delta = \min(\delta_1, \delta_2) \\\\ \Longrightarrow & \ 0 < |x - 1| < \delta_1 \text{ and } 0 < |x - 1| < \delta_2 \\\\
 \Longrightarrow & \  
\left|x^4 + \frac 1x - 2\right| \leq \left|x^4 - 1\right| + \left| \frac 1x - 1\right| < \frac\epsilon 2 + \frac\epsilon 2 = \epsilon
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

Others have posted solutions that provide excellent ways forward.  Here, we develop a "brute force" approach.

To that end, we first restrict $0<\delta<1/2$ so that for $|x-1|< \delta$, $\frac12<x<\frac32$.

Next, we see that for $|x-1|<1/2$

$$\begin{align}
\left|x^4+\frac1x-2\right|&=\left|\frac{x^5-2x+1}{x}\right|\\\\
&=\left|\frac{x^4+x^3+x^2+x-1}{x}\right|\,|x-1|\\\\
&\le\left(\frac{(3/2)^4+(3/2)^3+(3/2)^2+(3/2)+1}{1/2}\right)\,|x-1|\\\\
&=\frac{211}{8}|x-1|\tag 1
\end{align}$$

Now, note that given any number $\epsilon>0$, we can make the right-hand side of $(1)$ less than $\epsilon$ simply by ensuring that $|x-1|<\frac{\epsilon}{211/8}$.

Finally, choosing $\delta=\min \left(\frac12,\frac{8}{211}\epsilon\right)$, we have that given any $\epsilon >0$

$$\begin{align}
\left|x^4+\frac1x-2\right|&=\left|\frac{x^5-2x+1}{x}\right|<\epsilon
\end{align}$$

whenever $|x-1|<\delta$.

Comment: I think there is a typo. We have $$|x^{5} - 2x + 1| = |x^{5} - 1 - 2(x - 1)| = |x - 1||x^{4} + x^{3} + x^{2} + x - 1|$$ You have written $x + 1$ at the end of factorization. I am fixing this.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thanks for the catch.  +1

Comment: In the course of editing you made a further mistake/typo. Note that $$||x| - |y|| \leq |x - y| \leq |x| + |y|$$ and hence we should have $(3/2) + 1$ and not $(3/2) - 1$. Accordingly the number $179$ will change.

Comment: Thanks again!  Much appreciated.  Edited and same result as original post!